# How to grab bunch of dates that are these days?

Tags: php, mysql

In my db, I have list of dates and right now I am trying to get all the Monday dates? If that makes sense.

My db table includes:
Date Amount.

My code is:

```
$dt=strtotime('monday');
$day=date("D",$dt);
echo strttoupper($day);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `DATE` MySQL object, you could use the `DAYNAME` function, and search by that:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DAYNAME(date) = 'Monday'
```

In PHP/PDO-land, that would be:

```
foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DAYNAME(date) = 'Monday'") as $row) {
    // do stuff with $row
}
```